# Repeating a Macro in Excel untill it reaches a blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA in excel and I have recorded and modified a macro that gets a value then based on an "IF" statement it uses the answer to calculate a value in a certain cell . I need to repeat this until there is a blank cell in column A.

My Data is

Part Number  reported actual waste in the first 4 columns here follows my code that I need to repeat until column A is blank.

```
Sub MissingMix()
'
' MissingMix Macro
' Calculates Missing Mix based on scrap
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q

    Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
    Application.Goto Reference:="R3C8"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-5]-RC[-6]>0,SUM(RC[-5]-RC[-6])*RC[+1],"""")"
    Application.Goto Reference:="R3C9"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],'QAD Weights'!RC[-8]:R[37]C[-5],4)"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
' get active sheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Set CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

' defining starting row
Dim Values As Range
Set Values = Rows(5)

For i = 2 To Values.Cells.Count - 1
    If Values.Cells(i).Text <> "" Then

        ' Do Something ...

    End If
Next
```

you can also do the check with `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i).Value) Then ...`

**EDIT**

There is another way that you can handle this.

```
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Set CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

' getting the lastrow by jumping to the last filled row of cell(1,1)
' cell(1,1) means the cell at row=1 and column=1 (column "A")
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = CurrentSheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

MsgBox LastRow
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `.End(xlDown)` - if the column only has a value in cell A1 it will return 1048576 as the last row (same as selecting cell A1 and pressing Ctrl+Down).  Better to use `CurrentSheet.Cells(CurrentSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` instead.

Comment: Yeap, i understand that. That's why i suggested another answer. But using `xlUp` has a problem too. If there are blank cells in the middle you wouldn't be aware of them. If that's something you need to know, then you can't use that.

Comment: Moher, Thanks for your answer above  I can get it to work and yes it does display the number of rows in the worksheet but I cannot figure how to get the If and lookup functions to repeat so may times, This may be a silly question but like I said I am very very new to this. Thanks in advance

Comment: So Please explain more about your case. Maybe provide some sample data in a sheet. Show us exactly what you want.

Comment: Sum of Scrap 8/29/17  
Item Number Reported Actual
2436IDPAV2R 3 4
2436IDPAV2Y 4 4
2448idpav2r 2 2
2448idpav2Y 0 4
2448REPTHNDG 3 3
2448REPTHNR 4 13
2448REPTHNY 4 4
2460REPTHNR 14 36
2460REPTHNY 4 9
2460IDPAV2R 0 2
That is the data in the first 3 cols my macro calculates values in cols H and I the problem is to repeat the macro until column A is blank as the no of rows change daily. I apologize if this is simple but I am a total newbie

Comment: Mohler I tried to past the data in sheet form but I could not get it right

Comment: you want to iterate from the starting row of column A and at each iteration check for if the cell is blank and if not blank do your thing and continue to the next row. right? i want to be sure that i am understanding it right.

Comment: Yes Mohler that is it